# Angularjs Delay of few seconds in mobile web

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-href

I have used this in my code , it works fine on web , but on mobile web when this anchor tag is clicked there is a pause for 3-4 sec then it is redirected

<a ng-href="/menswear">Shirt</a>

how i can reduce this time in mobile web in angularjs

Comment: Have you added 'ngTouch' module to your angular app?

Comment: yes i have used ngTouch module , but on anchor tag we are using ng-href only , not ng-click

Comment: Without nfTouch touch, delay is possible invariable of href or click. If we eliminate this, check if you have any heavy code for the route's resolve params?